# Deleting database records using jQuery AJAX is not working

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, codeigniter-2

I am trying to delete records from database without reloading the page. In the view file I have the following code. But when I click on the delete link nothing happens. Would you please kindly help me find out where I have done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

My view file:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){ // added
        $('a.delete').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                var a_href = $('selector').attr('href');
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>student_fee_status/payment_info_delete",
                data: "id="+a_href,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#show").html(html);
                }
            });
         return false
        });
    }); // added
</script>


<?php if(count($records) > 0) { $i = 0; foreach ($records as $row){ $i++; ?>

<span> <?php echo $row['fee_type']; ?> : <?php echo $row['fee_amount']; ?> [<a id='<?php echo "$paymentid" ;?>'  
  class='delete' href='#'>Delete</a>]</span> <br>

<?php  }} ?>
```

This is my Controller:

```
function payment_info_delete(){

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);//Some clean up :)

    $query= $this->db->delete('studentpayment2', array('pid' => $id)); 

    echo "$id";

}
```

Comment: use firebug to see if your request gets to the correct url, and what is returned to find out more about the error

Comment: Firebug would pick this up - check the JS Console to find out what might be going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to put the '`var a_href...`' line outside of the ajax function
2. You need to replace the word selector with `this` which refers to the currently clicked element.

   `var a_href = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({...`

Comment: That's a very good point - I didn't even notice that the variable declaration was inside the `.ajax` calls options.

Comment: Thank you Ash. It is now passing data and deleting the database record. If you have time would you please kindly tell me one thing.. when I click on the delete link to delete data it works fine now but it still shows the data on the view page. If I refresh the page then its gone. How can I make it gone the very moment I click on the delete link? Thanks Again

Comment: You need to add something to your success function e.g. `$('a.delete').hide();` or if you want to be more specific assign the element to a variable and call `hide()` on that : `var el = $(this);` and in the success function: `el.hide();`

Comment: Thank you very much Ash. You just taught me how to delete and hide using jquery  AJAX . ANd thanks to Anthony Grist too. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a_href = $('selector').attr('href');
$.ajax({...
```

Comment: @Srijon '$('selector')' you should change it by the right selector, i think it's '$('a.delete')'

Answer (score 1):

As mgraph pointed out in his answer, the `var a_href = $('selector').attr('href');` line is incorrect. You want to replace `'selector'` with `this` so that you're getting the href attribute from the anchor that was clicked on.

That said, I think that's still probably wrong - surely you want to be passing back the id of the entry to delete, which seems to be stored in the `id` attribute of the anchor tag, rather than always passing back a `#` symbol?

To pass the id back instead, rather than the href, replace this:
`var a_href = $('selector').attr('href');`
with this:
`var a_href = this.id;`

Comment: Exactly .. I want to pass the id value of the anchor tag and use it to delete data. I have tried - var a_href = $('a.delete').attr('href'); but it doesn't work. Would you please kindly tell me the how to pass the id value of my anchor tag?

Comment: @Srijon I've edited my answer to include what you should replace the `var a_href = ...` line with, try that and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Anthony Grist. As per Ash's suggestion I have put the 'var a_href...' line outside of the ajax function and used var a_href = $(this).attr('href'); $.ajax({... it is working perfectly now. Thanks a lot. :) –